# How to display all sub items related to stock item for each checkbox

Tags: acumatica

How can I display all related Sub items in the next Grid for each selected checkbox, based on my image the selected one is InventoryID (301CMPST01) and (301CMPST02), these items have corresponding sub items and we renamed it as "Color" and "Size", Please check my image.

[image: Displaying Subitems]

This image is the Sub Items of InventoryID (301CMPST01) as I mentioned to be displayed in the 2nd Grid of the last image.

[image: Inventory Sub Items]

Comment: 1. In which screen you are watching? 2. In which tables those entities live?

Comment: This is from add stock item (SOSiteStatus) in salesorder screen, we just customized it to have another grid view below.

Comment: Can you please tell me the name of the form in format ar301000, because as programmer I do care about programming prospective, not business logic name

Comment: Here's the screen name for the SO "SO301000".